# CSRF protections cause "Invalid or Unexpected Token" error

Tags: javascript, php, csrf-protection

I am trying to integrate CSRF protection on my forms, and I have started with my registration form that started out working before the CSRF tokens were added, but now just produce a "Invalid or Unexpected Token" error. Here is my current form:

```
    <form method="post" name="registration_form" action="<?php echo esc_url($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="<?= $token_id; ?>" value="<?= $token_value; ?>" />
                First Name: <input type="text" name='<?=$form_names['firstname'];?>' id='firstname' /><br>
                Last Name: <input type="text" name='<?=$form_names['lastname'];?>' id='lastname' /><br>
                Phone: <input type="tel" name='<?=$form_names['phone'];?>' id='phone' /><br>            
                Email: <input type="email" name="<?=$form_names['email'];?>" id="email" /><br>
                Username: <input type="text" name='<?=$form_names['username'];?>' id='username' /><br>
                Password: <input type="password"
                                 name="<?=$form_names['password'];?>" 
                                 id="password"/><br>
                Confirm password: <input type="password" 
                                         name="<?=$form_names['passwordconf'];?>" 
                                         id="confirmpwd" /><br>
                <input type="button" 
                       value="Register" 
                       onclick="return regformhash(this.form,
                                       this.form.<?=$form_names['firstname'];?>,
                                       this.form.<?=$form_names['lastname'];?>,
                                       this.form.<?=$form_names['phone'];?>,
                                       this.form.<?=$form_names['username'];?>,
                                       this.form.<?=$form_names['email'];?>,
                                       this.form.<?=$form_names['password'];?>,
                                       this.form.<?=$form_names['passwordconf'];?>);" /> 
            </form>
</body>
```

I have included a hidden field with a name/value pair token, as well as random tokens for each name field. The tokens all work as intended, so the issue isn't in generating them. There is also a Javascript file that validates form entry, I don't know if it is relevant, but here is the js validation:

```
function regformhash(form, firstname, lastname, phone, username, email, password, confirmpwd) {
    // Check each field has a value
    if (firstname.value == '' || lastname.value == '' || phone.value == '' || email.value == '' || password.value == '' || confirmpwd.value == '') {
        alert('You must provide all the requested details. Please try again');
        return false;
    }

       // Check the First Name
    re = /^[A-Za-z\s]+$/; 
    if(!re.test(form.firstname.value)) { 
        alert("First Name must contain only upper and lower case letters. Please try again"); 
        form.firstname.focus();
        return false; 
    }

      // Check the Last Name
    re = /^[A-Za-z\s]+$/; 
    if(!re.test(form.lastname.value)) { 
        alert("Last Name must contain only upper and lower case letters. Please try again"); 
        form.lastname.focus();
        return false; 
    }

      // Check the Phone Number
    re = /\d{3}[\-]\d{3}[\-]\d{4}/; 
    if(!re.test(form.phone.value)) { 
        alert("Phone Number must be formatted as follows, xxx-xxx-xxxx or (xxx) xxx-xxxx. Please try again"); 
        form.phone.focus();
        return false; 
    }


    // Check the username
    re = /^\w+$/; 
    if(!re.test(form.username.value)) { 
        alert("Username must contain only letters, numbers and underscores. Please try again"); 
        form.username.focus();
        return false; 
    }

    // Check that the password is sufficiently long (min 6 chars)
    // The check is duplicated below, but this is included to give more
    // specific guidance to the user
    if (password.value.length < 6) {
        alert('Passwords must be at least 6 characters long.  Please try again');
        form.password.focus();
        return false;
    }

    // At least one number, one lowercase and one uppercase letter 
    // At least six characters 
    var re = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}/; 
    if (!re.test(password.value)) {

       alert('Passwords must contain at least one number, one lowercase and one uppercase letter.  Please try again');
        return false;
    }

    // Check password and confirmation are the same
    if (password.value != confirmpwd.value) {
        alert('Your password and confirmation do not match. Please try again');
        form.password.focus();
        return false;
    }

    // Create a new element input, this will be our hashed password field. 
    var p = document.createElement("input");

    // Add the new element to our form. 
    form.appendChild(p);
    p.name = "p";
    p.type = "hidden";
    p.value = hex_sha512(password.value);

    // Make sure the plaintext password doesn't get sent. 
    password.value = "";
    confirmpwd.value = "";

    // Finally submit the form. 
    form.submit();
    return true;
}
```

I don't know if the parameter names need to match up with the form names, they didn't all before and it worked.

Finally, the "Invalid or Unexpected Token" error was pointing to the closing `</body>`, if that helps as well.

Update:

I'm going to go more in depth about how this particular CSRF is working for this particular form. The form has an include to another php file, called register.inc.php, that does a series of sanitizations when adding data to the database, but I decided to also use it for the CSRF check. Here is the base code that relates to the CSRF (note, I haven't added the sanitization functions inside of the if statement yet, I'm trying to get the form to work without it before I add it in. I have a comment where it will eventually go):

```
include 'csrf.class.php';
require 'Sessions/session.class.php';
$session = new session();
// Set to true if using https
$session->start_session('_s', false);

$csrf = new csrf();


// Generate Token Id and Valid
$token_id = $csrf->get_token_id();
$token_value = $csrf->get_token($token_id);

// Generate Random Form Names
$form_names = $csrf->form_names(array('firstname','lastname','phone','email', 'username', 'password','passwordconf'), false);


if(isset($_POST[$form_names['email']], $_POST[$form_names['password']])) {
        // Check if token id and token value are valid.
        if($csrf->check_valid('post')) {
                // Get the Form Variables.


                // Add Sanitization function here
        }
        // Regenerate a new random value for the form.
        $form_names = $csrf->form_names(array('email', 'password'), true);
}
```

Here is the csrf.class.php that is being referenced here:

```
<?php

class csrf{

    public function get_token_id() {
        if(isset($_SESSION['token_id'])) { 
                return $_SESSION['token_id'];
        } else {
                $token_id = $this->random(10);
                $_SESSION['token_id'] = $token_id;
                return $token_id;
        }
}
public function get_token() {
        if(isset($_SESSION['token_value'])) {
                return $_SESSION['token_value']; 
        } else {
                $token = hash('sha512', $this->random(500));
                $_SESSION['token_value'] = $token;
                return $token;
        }

}
public function check_valid($method) {
        if($method == 'post' || $method == 'get') {
                $post = $_POST;
                $get = $_GET;
                if(isset(${$method}[$this->get_token_id()]) && (${$method}[$this->get_token_id()] == $this->get_token())) {
                        return true;
                } else {
                        return false;   
                }
        } else {
                return false;   
        }
}
public function form_names($names, $regenerate) {

        $values = array();
        foreach ($names as $n) {
                if($regenerate == true) {
                        unset($_SESSION[$n]);
                }
                $s = isset($_SESSION[$n]) ? $_SESSION[$n] : $this->random(10);
                $_SESSION[$n] = $s;
                $values[$n] = $s;       
        }
        return $values;
}
private function random($len) {
        if (function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes')) {
                $byteLen = intval(($len / 2) + 1);
                $return = substr(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($byteLen)), 0, $len);
        } elseif (@is_readable('/dev/urandom')) {
                $f=fopen('/dev/urandom', 'r');
                $urandom=fread($f, $len);
                fclose($f);
                $return = '';
        }

        if (empty($return)) {
                for ($i=0;$i<$len;++$i) {
                        if (!isset($urandom)) {
                                if ($i%2==0) {
                                             mt_srand(time()%2147 * 1000000 + (double)microtime() * 1000000);
                                }
                                $rand=48+mt_rand()%64;
                        } else {
                                $rand=48+ord($urandom[$i])%64;
                        }

                        if ($rand>57)
                                $rand+=7;
                        if ($rand>90)
                                $rand+=6;

                        if ($rand==123) $rand=52;
                        if ($rand==124) $rand=53;
                        $return.=chr($rand);
                }
        }

        return $return;
}
}
```

When the form is submitted, it saves the CSRF tokens from the form in a Session and compares it to the Tokens in the Post value. If the two match, then it continues with the code. Here is the site I used to create the CSRF protection, [Prevent CSRF](http://www.wikihow.com/Prevent-Cross-Site-Request-Forgery-(CSRF)-Attacks-in-PHP).

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you have to do form processing/validation through JavaScript? I am not sure if this is even a PHP question. Why not do back-end validation and form processing through PHP and front-end validation through some sort of JS/jQuery validation plugin ?

Comment: The Javascript is a front end validation, it let's the user know if they entered improper information before the form is submitted, as well as ensure proper formatting of the information they enter in. I also have back end validation in PHP that sanitizes user input and uses prepared statements to add the data to the database. What I am doing, though, is adding CSRF protection to my forms using the tokens as shown above, but it seems to be causing an error, and I can't pinpoint where it is. I don't even know if the js is interfering or not, I just added it in case it was.

Comment: Do you have the error reporting turned on for your PHP and the PHP form processing code? If yes then can you update your question with the additional PHP code? How are you implementing token/CSRF protection in PHP ?

Comment: What are the values of $token_id and $token_value when you render the form? Also how are you storing and checking the CSRF protection? Is it in the session?

Comment: @kyle the $token_id and $token_value are randomly generated. I'm going to expand my answer to, show the process that is currently in place.

Comment: @Maximus2012 I do have error reporting, but it didn't report any errors for this particular script. I only found the error in the Chrome Console. I have also updated my question with more information on how it is being implemented.

Comment: Where is the part where you are passing the token value as a form field ? If I understand correctly, the token has to be generated on the first page, saved as a hidden form field so that it could be passed to the 2nd page and then the token gets validated on the 2nd page. Is that what you are doing ?

Comment: Yes, the hidden field is at the top of the form. When it is submitted, it goes to the register.inc.php file and then gets sent to the $csrf->check_valid function to check to see if it is valid.

Comment: I think I might have a possible solution to my problem. On the Javascript file, there are sections referencing the form as follows: form.firstname, form.lastname, etc. Obviously those aren't going to match up with the CSRF tokens generated on the form, so I am going to try and modify the js to add those tokens in. I'll check back when I'm done.